# My PHP Script dont want to create a ZIP File

Tags: php

I tried to code a script, that put some data in a zip file. I think I have done all right, but he does not create the zip file.

I already tried a lot, but don´t find the issue.

```php
<?php
$sql_abfrage_cloud = "SELECT * FROM dateien WHERE code = '$zugang' ORDER BY id"; 
$abfrage_cloud = $mysqli->query($sql_abfrage_cloud);
$verzeichnis = '/upload/';
$zip_name = date("dHis").'_fc.zip';             
$anz_dateien = 0;
$error = 'fatal';
while($fetch = $abfrage_cloud->fetch_assoc()){
    $anz_dateien = $anz_dateien + 1;
    $zip_datei[$anz_dateien] = $fetch['path'];
}
$zip_arch = new ZipArchive;
$status = $zip_arch->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if($status==true){
    foreach($zip_datei as $datei){
        $zip_arch->addFile($verzeichnis.$datei, $datei);
    }                                                                                      

    if(file_exists($zip_name)){
        $error = 'false';
    } else {
        $error = 'true';
    }
}
?>
```

I expected that $error would be 'false' but it´s 'true'.

Comment: What debugging have you already done?  What _does_ happen when you run the script?

Comment: Where is `$zugang` defined?  How do you know that `$error` is `true` when you're not actually _checking_ the value of `$error` anywhere?

Comment: @PatrickQ `$zugang` is defined an I check `$error`, you just can´t see it, because the script is about 500 lines and I dont wanted to post all this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `$zip_arch->close()` to save finish writing the file.

You should also use `===` when comparing the result of `$zip_archive->open()`, since the non-true results are numbers, and any non-zero number compares equal to `true` when type juggling is allowed.

```
$zip_arch = new ZipArchive;
$status = $zip_arch->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if($status===true){
    foreach($zip_datei as $datei){
        $zip_arch->addFile($verzeichnis.$datei, $datei);
    }                                                                                      
    $zip_arch->close();

    if(file_exists($zip_name)){
        $error = 'false';
    } else {
        $error = 'true';
    }
}
```

Comment: The lack of `close()` was my first suspicion too, but the docs do say "This method is automatically called at the end of the script".  Is your experience to the contrary?

Comment: @PatrickQ But he's checking whether the file exists *before* the end of the script.

Comment: Ah, for that part, yes.  It wouldn't explain the file not actually being created though, which OP also seems to be claiming "but he does not create the zip file"

Comment: I assumed he was just using the value of `$error` when determining whether the file was created, not checking it separately.

Comment: @Barmar First thank you for your answer. I changed my script, but `$error` is still 'true' and there is no ZIP on my server. I tested a lot... He found the files I want to put in the ZIP, but he don´t create a ZIP..

Comment: Are you sure `$zip_arch->open()` is succeeding? Also, check the return values of `$zip_archi->addFile()`.

Comment: @JulianLay To add to Barmar's last comment, notice the difference between your check of `if($status==true)` and Barmar's check of `($status===true)`.  `open()` will return a status code if it fails, and this status code will be considered a truthy value, hence the need for type checking.

Comment: @Barmar Yup, just putting it in direct context of your prior comment, as some users here are very likely to answer "Are you sure `$zip_arch->open()` is succeeding?" with "Yes, it passed my `if($result == true)` test!"